# Is there a way to filter a CQWP or DVWP using Metadata column values?

Tags: managed-metadata

I have a SharePoint 2010 list containing a metadata column. 
Is there a way to filter list values on a data view web part or a Content query web part using the metadata values?

For example: I have tags like: ProductA, ProductB, ProductC for Items in a list
Can I have the CQWP or DVWP show only the items where metadata contains (ProductA)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the ECM team blog:

> ... is one of the new Managed Metadata fields, which the CQWP fully supports, including the
> single & multi-value varieties. While not shown in this example, the CQWP also supports
> filtering over the Enterprise Keywords columns & the “All Tags” column which lets you look
> for any managed metadata tag on a queried item, regardless of which metadata field on the
> item contains the tag.

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ecm/whats-new-with-the-content-query-web-part)

So, yes you can filter on a MMS field.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the CQWP will let you do this with the Managed Metadata column (or multiple choice or multiple lookup columns).

However, you could easily write your own web part for it, and use the SPSiteDataQuery object to get the items you want. I mean, there must be a way to do that sort of query in CAML, right? I'm pretty sure the restrictions lie in the CQWP itself.